# Dash Datatable editable=True не работает

Tags: python, plotly

В одной из таблиц не работает параметр editable=True, вот код этой таблицы:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
       id='to-add-row-table',
       columns=to_add_columns,
       dropdown={
            'Наименование': {
                 'options': to_add_names
             }
       },
       data=[
             first_record
       ],
       editable=True,
       style_cell={'width': '100px', 'height': '0', 'visibility': 'hidden'},
       style_data={'background-color': TO_ADD_COLOR, 'visibility': 'visible',},
       style_table={'border': '1 px solid blue'})
```

Собственно, таблица просто не редактируется и все, любые данные предоставлю (стили css везде убирал, ставил и убирал callback'и на эту таблицу, не помогло)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм действий:

1. для начала просто выполните [код из примера (Adding or removing rows)](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/editable) один-в-один, ничего не меняя
2. подставьте ваши данные и убедитесь, что код работает правильно
3. после этого можно попробовать менять стили, наводить красоту и т.д.

идея в том, чтобы отловить тот шаг (изменение) после которого таблица перестает редактироваться

Comment: Я поменял id таблицы и все заработало, значит дело в callback'ах скорее всего (вообще, у меня 2 таблицы с одинаковым id, одна пустая для callback'a, так как вторая таблица генерируется в процессе работе и без 1-й таблицы программа бы не запустилась, но не думаю, что это проблема). Я проверил свои callback'и, с ними вроде все в порядке, но я могу выложить их код, отредактировав вопрос